# How to remove root element shadow in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

If we scroll upper then top of the page or lower, then bottom of the page you will see page frame with shadow in the Chrome.

[image: page shadow]

Is there any any to remove it?
Background is set for html element

```
  background-image url('../images/belly.png')
  background-position  50% 50%
  background-repeat no-repeat
  background-attachment fixed
  background-size cover
```

Comment: This might be applicable (though I wouldn't add code to solve this issue  -- which is really a function of the browser and OS): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046315/prevent-overscolling-of-web-page

Comment: no, because I can't set `overflow: hidden;` to html :(