# Prevent "overscroll" on fullscreen web app like Google Maps do

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, iframe, overscroll

Chrome on Mac has a bug that will be probably fixed in version <strike>42</strike> 41: [Switching tab affects “overscroll” (aka elastic rubber band)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465061)

tl;dr:

1. Chrome on Mac has this annoying "overscroll" aka rubber band effect on the whole document.
2. It can be [prevented with CSS (SO post).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046315/prevent-overscolling-of-web-page)
3. When you go to http://wikibudgets.org/sankey the overscroll is disabled - try to scroll to zoom the diagram, the document stays in place.
4. when you switch to any other tab and then go back the overscroll effect is not disabled any more - try to scroll to zoom the diagram, the document jumps up and down.

**5. [Google Maps website](https://www.google.co.uk/maps) does not suffer from this bug so there must be a workaround.**

Any idea or advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the bug is already fixed in **Version 41.0.2272.76 (64-bit)**