# How to prevent white space "bounce" after scrolling to the top of the page and the bottom

Tags: html, css

A lot of websites have this thing that if you scroll all the way up you get this "bounce" effect as if your page bounced off the top of your browser window revealing white space at the top of the window.

The same situation if you scroll down, you get the same exact "bounce" effect.

This bounce can look very ugly if your header and footer has a background colour.

How do i get rid of this effect?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <header></header>

  <div></div>

  <footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 140px;
}

div {
  height: 1000px;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
  height: 140px;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent "overscrolling" of web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046315/prevent-overscrolling-of-web-page)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I had similar issue this worked for me.

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Latest Chrome at date of this comment. Samsung Galaxy S22+.

Answer (score 34):

So, the accepted answer doesn't work for me. I have to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior

So,

```
body {
    overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked in my specific case. Setting it to html should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use default bg

```
html,body{
     overscroll-behavior: auto;
     background: var(--color-bg-header);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the top answers worked for me by themselves, but when combined it worked fine.

```
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overscroll-behavior: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What ended up being best for me was adding `style="overflow:hidden"` directly on the `<html>` tag (via css didn't do it).

This of course prevents the page itself from moving on scroll, but in my case it's a web app where individual elements scroll independently within the page, so this is the effect I was looking for.

On mobile, I reverted back via `overflow:auto !important` in a media query.

Answer (score -2):

You can remove that effect by applying the following style:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

This make the content only inside you body to be scroll-able.

Comment: This did not work for some reason. The below answer did though, marking him as correct.